# Minecraft flickers when moving around

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A while ago my Minecraft started to flicker. The screen flashes once in a while when I move around. It doesn't when I stay still, just when there is movement. Any help? I would try to take a screen shot but it's really hard to catch, happens really randomly and rapid. When in survival the creative menu flashes instead of just a white flash. This is in singleplayer.

Edit: tried deleting and re-installing Minecraft. Also tried other versions of the game through the launcher. Still flickers... Drivers are fully up to date

This is on a razor laptop with NVIDIA 765 and Intel i7

Comment: Are you using any texture packs? what graphical settings are you using?

Comment: Turning vsync on might help

Comment: @Ben No texture packs, vsync was already on, turning it off still has the flicker plus lag on the amplified feature. Render distance 8, graphics fast. Max frame rate 120. The computer has a Nvidia GTX 765 and a quad core i7 processor.

Comment: Are your drivers up-to-date?

Comment: I've seen weird rendering issues over 6 chunk render distance on 1.8 if you use the default of 1GB of ram.  If you have 64-bit computer/Java, you can try bumping up the amount of ram assigned to Minecraft and see if it helps.

Comment: You could definitely turn your settings up more than that... that's a way better processor than mine and I use 10 chunks and fancy graphics pretty successfully (though the 1.8 release does have some problems). I know this doesn't solve your issue, I'm just saying.

Comment: @Johonn I believe the drivers are up to date, it's not just happening in 1.8 I've tried in other version and it still happens and I've also tried to re-install minecraft and it still happens. I'll update my question to further explain what I've done

Comment: Is this single player or multiplayer? If you're connecting to a server could the flicker be server lag?

Comment: @Ardavion It's on single player, on lan it seems to be worse

Comment: @mellamokb It happens on all versions sadly

Comment: Change screen hz frequency.

Comment: I haven't played Minecraft in a while so I don't know if this would work, but have you tried installing [OptiFine](https://optifine.net/home). I'm not sure what kind of effect it would have, but considering you've uninstalled and reinstalled, it might be worth a try.

Comment: @ardaozkal How does one go about doing that? Is it the frame limit?

Comment: Are you playing on a desktop or laptop?

Comment: @virusboy I think "what are your computer specs?" woukd be a better wuestion here

Comment: I am sorry for the errors but my phone is a piece of c...

Comment: No, I am not asking for specs, I am asking what he is using.

Comment: @BakedPotato can you run a programme that reads out the GPU temperature and see if your GPU is overheating (around 100°C) when the flickering apears?

Comment: @virusboy but is is also good to have a full list of his specs so we can work on that

Comment: Thank you all for your help. No the pc wasn't over heating. The specs were listed above (well above the recommended for Minecraft) and the computer used was a Razer laptop. And I have managed to resolve the problem on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an incredibly long amount of time, this problem has finally been resolved. If I ran Minecraft through steam the flickers stopped. Why there were flickers and what caused this is still unknown, perhaps a bug in the programming.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a performance issue.

First of all, try different video settings. Such as turning Fancy to Fast if it's on, no smooth lighting and render distance to minimal chunks. Just try scrolling through them and see what the effect is on your performance.

If that does not help, check your ram allocation using F3, and look in the upper-right corner of the screen. If that gets above around 70-80 %, (depending on preference) add more ram to Minecraft. (Remember you need to make sure other programs can still run without Minecraft consuming all the ram so that might be a problem)

You can do this in the profile editor under Java settings (advanced). In JVM Arguments you will see that you can input how much ram you want Minecraft to be running on. In this box you fill in:

> "-Xmx2048M -Xms2048M" for 2GB ram
>
> "-Xmx4096M -Xms4096M" for 4GB ram

To add more, add 1024 to the numbers for an extra gigabyte.

eg, 4096 (4GB) + 1024 = 5120 (5GB)

If that does not help, try deleting your .minecraft folder in it's respective location.

**Mac:** /Library/minecraft
**Windows:** Press Windows+R, type "%appdata%/.minecraft" and press enter.

**But make sure you back the folder up!**

Many people have used this technique for similar problems without: eg. Internet connection, so the launcher could not re-download the folder. This is also the folder were world saves and texture-packs are stored so again, **back it up first.**

if that does not help you need to wait for new vidcard drivers that might solve the problem.

Comment: *sigh* Please, fix your grammar. (I completely understand if your not a native English speaker though)

Comment: i am a dutch italian

Comment: Ok then. I understand. Your very good none the less though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a NVIDIA graphic card, this may be caused by threaded optimization. To disable it, open the nvidia control panel (in the windows control panel), get in the 3D settings and set the threaded optimization parameter to disabled.

Answer (score 1):

It has happened to me before. To fix it I reset my render distance to the lowest and played for a bit. Then I turned it back up. Try pressing F3+A to reload all your chunks if all else fails.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but on Multiplayer with Optifine - I was even going to ask a question until I figured out that if the Render Distance is 10 or over, some areas of the world glitch:
[image: Problem: Render Distance 10 and above]
Which I fixed by changing the Render Distance to 9:
[image]
Hope this helps, ***Zoweb***

Comment: Hi Zoweb, the problem wasn't some graphical glitch but a legit flicker. It would work normally and then white flashes would appear in a flickering manor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple solution before you try reinstalling/changing drivers/etc.

Instead of running the Minecraft window full screen, resize the window to be just a little less than full screen. This fixed the problem for me running Minecraft on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Go to options - video settings and turn Vsync off. I can't say if it will work for you but it did work for me, at least for now.

Answer (score 1):

heres how to fix.

1. turn down in-game settings
2. open NVidia control panel
3. select "adjust image settings with preview"
4. select "use my preference emphasizing"
5. adjust to "balanced"
6. select "configure surround PhysX" on the left
7. change processor to nvidia

Answer (score 1):

I was running on integrated graphics. Changing to my 1050ti fixed it.

I had to go to Nvidia control panel, Manage 3D Settings, then change Auto-Select to Dedicated GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [latest Java release](http://www.java.com/). If you already have it, uninstall and reinstall it.

If the problem still occurs, Try to get the [**Java 7 update 6X or 7X**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html) version instead of the brand new Java 8 update 25.

Comment: this is probbebly a preforamce issue rather than a java issue

Answer (score 0):

it works for me look what to do

1. go on lowest chunk render mean to 2
2. play 5 minutes
3. put it back to the number that was set before but DONT start the game only stay in menu
4. close the game
5. an java error will appear
6. press close program
7. open the game and it will not flick again

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I had the same problem for the longest time. I finally found that if you RIGHT CLICK the  minecraft icon and click the 'run with processor' drop down menu. Click the non-default processor (mines High-performance NVIDIA processor) This has stopped my screen glitching, but keep in mind that you need to do this EVERYTIME you start up minecraft.

Comment: Do you think there is a way to set this as default?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

Enable `options > Video Settings > USE VBOs`

When I play without the GPU I have no problems, but when I plug in my R7260x I get this issue. For some reason, the bug happens only when I switch between the **worlds**. Below are some prints of the **bug** and my **video settings**. As you can see, I could not see anything:

- [video settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kITse.png)
- [textures flickering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue2Jp.png)
- [textures flickering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsFBz.png)
- [textures flickering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH8FV.png)

## Obs

My problem was not JAVA

Answer (score 0):

So I realize this post is SUPER old by now, but since I stumbled upon this problem recently, I thought I'd touch base on how I fixed it. Firstly, I use MultiMC, and this still solved the issue, but I tried it on both MultiMc and the standard minecraft launcher.

Right click on either MultiMC or the standard MC launcher, click properties, click advanced and the check the box that reads "Always run as administrator" I havn't any clue how that solved it, but it fixed both my standard MC and all instances in MultiMC I currently had created. My specific graphic issue was when opening my inventory, my character would glitch out across the screen, and while roaming about item's sprites would just stretch out across the screen. This saves you the trouble of CONSTANTLY having to right click and "run as admin" so. There ya go!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting chunk loading to default, Solved it for me.