# Minecraft world flickering

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a problem, my minecraft worlds are flickering. It's like it can't decide what to generate.

Here is a pic: 
[image: Image showing the problem]

I have tried restarting minecraft, creating new worlds, restarting the computer...

This happens to every single world after a while. I hope someone knows how to fix it.

Comment: Disable or enable VBOs. Try installing OptiFine. Update drivers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/188303/104387

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per rivermont - Will B.'s comment.

Answer (score -1):

You game is corrupt and you need to delete and reinstall Minecraft. Don't worry you won't lose anything if you sign back into your account. Bye have a good day.

Comment: OP already tried this by the looks of the comments.  It seems that it was video related and not MC related.